# How to remove common letters in two Strings in iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

How can i remove common letters in two strings and generate a new string using remaining unique letters ?

for example:

```
String 1= Optimus Prime,
String 2= Deja Thoras,
```

new string should be: `Djaha`

Comment: Don't you mean "How to remove characters from one string in another string?"

Comment: Looks like homework to me. It should be marked as such.

Comment: Pawan, you can't change the question after a lot of people have answered. The original answer asked for a process which resulted in "Djaha". If you have a different question, please make a new question.

Comment: @futureelite7 No it shouldn't. The homework tag has been removed since long. Read all about it somewhere on Meta.

Comment: I have reverted the last edit of this question, because otherwise nobody will understand the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just enumerate through the characters in the string and delete matching ranges. Be sure to search 'caselessly' (ie the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters is irrelevant). The following snippet logs "Djaha", as the opening post expects.

```
NSString *firstString = @"Deja Thoras";
NSString *secondString = @"Optimus Prime";

NSMutableString *outputString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:firstString];

[outputString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, firstString.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences 
usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([secondString rangeOfString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        [outputString deleteCharactersInRange:substringRange];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
```

If this is a common operation, I would place the code into a category, with a method name like `stringByRemovingMatchingCharactersInString:`

Comment: +1 for using `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` to enumerate characters.

Comment: Please mark as answered if it is working for you borrrden, so this question can be considered closed.

Comment: It's not my question @BenjaminMayo hahahaha

Comment: And yes, `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` is much better than performing for-loop iteration, as not only does it make more semantic sense, but it silently handles different locales and languages for you.

Comment: @BenjaminMayo: thanks bro. but for more clarity i corrected the question.would you mind looking it once more

Comment: Pawan, mark an answer as correct and then open a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way that avoids the nitty gritty of character enumeration:

```
NSString *string1 = @"Deja Thoras";
NSString *string2 = @"Optimus Prime";

NSCharacterSet *filterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string2];
NSString *filteredString = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:filterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: The output I got by running this was "OptimuPim" so this doesn't work correctly.  I think you are not adding in the letters from the second string (as well as reducing duplicates).

Comment: @borrrden What I'm doing is removing the characters contained in string from another string. I thought the OP wanted this rather than what you described due to the expected result of "Djaha". Also, I focused on the character removal and ignored case sensitivity.

Comment: I see now.  If you reverse the two strings and put in case sensitivity then it works.  Clever!

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe : thanks for the help. for more clarity i have edited question here,

How can i remove repeated letters in two strings combined and generate a new string using remaining unique letters ?

for example:

String 1= optimusprime,
String 2= dejathoras,
combined string : optimusprimedejathoras

now by removing repeated letters,

new string should be: optimusredjah,

the thing is that, only one type of letter should be there in new string, not repeated (as you can see in example)

Comment: @PawanJoshi As others have said, you can't edit a question with existing answers in a way that invalidates the answers. Instead, you should make a new post with your changed question. That being said, you should really think about the question first and if the specification makes sense. For example with the way you ask the question now it's unclear why there are two strings at all. If the strings are concatenated before removing the duplicate characters there's no need to add the complication of having two arguments.