# How to remove common letters in two Strings in iOS SDK?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I remove repeated letters in two strings combined and generate a new string using remaining unique letters ?

for example:

```
String 1= optimusprime;
String 2= dejathoras;
combined string : optimusprimedejathoras;
```

now by removing repeated letters,

new string should be: optimusredjah,

the thing is that, only one type of letter should be there in new string, not repeated (as you can see in example)

Comment: You have asked the smae wuestion already..?!

Comment: @Filip: previous one was not cleared and was on hold. so i corrected the question and asked again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed similar as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422371/1187415)
to your previous question:

```
NSString *string1 = @"optimusprime";
NSString *string2 = @"dejathoras";

// Combine strings:
NSString *combined = [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2];

// Now remove duplicate characters:
NSMutableString *result = [combined mutableCopy];
[result enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [result length])
               options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                // Check if current character already occurred at an earlier location:
                NSRange previousRange = [result rangeOfString:substring
                                      options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, substringRange.location)];
                if (previousRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [result deleteCharactersInRange:substringRange];
                }
            }];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Output: `optimusredjah`

**EDIT:** The above solution does not scale very well. Storing duplicate characters
in a *dictionary*, as suggested in @waf's answer, or in a *set*, is probably better:

```
NSMutableString *result = [combined mutableCopy];
NSMutableSet *chars = [NSMutableSet set];
[result enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [result length])
               options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                if ([chars containsObject:substring]) {
                    [result deleteCharactersInRange:substringRange];
                } else {
                    [chars addObject:substring];
                }

            }];
```

Comment: thanks Martin R: you are a saviour...:)

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to iterate through all characters in each string and track the count in a dictionary. Then go througj each key and print the key once to a string. Not sure if order matters.

If order matters then everytime you "log" a string and it hasnt been seen before you append to an initially empty string.

Pseudo code: jointString = first+second. For each char in joint, if NSMutableDict !have, insert char , and finalString = finalString + thisChar.

Comment: what about first string's characters ??
how can they be removed??